# Is there client / agent software for Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, client, agent

One of the stated benefits of Ansible is the agent-less architecture. Ansible uses Python and this is almost always pre-installed on any distribution. So there is no need for a client or agent on machines where Ansible need to do its magic.

Recent experience made we wonder if this is true in practice.

So for example current Ansible offers modules for generating certificates as described in the article [Generating self-signed OpenSSL certs with Ansible 2.4's crypto modules | Jeff Geerling](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/generating-self-signed-openssl-certs-ansible-24s-crypto-modules)

But if you use these you will additionally need: pip, python-dev. Those dependencies will initially fail because you need to provide values for `python_version` and `python_user`.

Things get messy quick now. We are creating a Python dev environment on the target machine to create a self signed certificate. A host of other stuff is dragged in for example

python,python-dev,python3,python3-dev,make,gcc,python-pip,python3-pip,build-essential,libssl-dev,zlib1g-dev,libbz2-dev,libreadline-dev,libsqlite0-dev,wget,curl,llvm,libncurses5-dev,libncursesw5-dev,xz-utils,tk-dev,git,libffi-dev,libxml2-dev,libxslt1-dev,libyaml-dev

Now mind you, we are creating self signed certificates using modules that are default part of Ansible now. Those modules however require stuff that is not part of any standard Python distribution on Linux.

In actual fact, to create a self signed certificate - which is typically done with a few bash commands - we are building a one off custom Ansible client. This might very well fail for example with a message like

> Failed to import the required Python library (setuptools) on
>   myserver's Python /usr/bin/python

So my conclusion at this point is that Ansible is not truly agent-less and does in fact require a client / agent of some sort on the target machine. This client / agent is just downloaded, compiled, linked, configured on the fly.

If we are required to do this just to use a standard Ansible module, we have effectively proven that there is a need for a Ansible client and / or agent of some sort.

No official Ansible client / agent will be forthcoming of course because Ansible is touted as being agent-less and not requiring anything else than Python.

But maybe someone took the trouble of creating such a client? Is there an installer of some sort that will install all dependencies for the modules that Ansible claims to support?

Comment: "agent-less" means it uses `ssh` to execute every possible command, while an agent may listen on some ports and receive such as HTTP messages and apply changes. There is no surprise that you need some dependencies to do something. Even you say you can generate certificates through bash commands, you first need OpenSSL to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: " Ansible offers modules for generating certificates ... But if you use these you will additionally need: pip, python-dev. Those dependencies will initially fail because you need to provide values for python_version and python_user. Things get messy quick now ...
>
> We are creating self signed certificates using modules that are default part of Ansible now. Those modules however require stuff that is not part of any standard Python distribution on Linux.

A: [openssl_certificate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/openssl_certificate_module.html#openssl-certificate-generate-and-or-check-openssl-certificates) module requieres

> - PyOpenSSL >= 0.15 or cryptography >= 1.6 (if using selfsigned or assertonly provider)
> - acme-tiny (if using the acme provider)

This is all that is needed in Ubuntu 18.04 and FreeBSD 11.3 and 12.0. See details in [certificate](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/certificate) Ansible Galaxy role.

[Debian vars](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-certificate/blob/master/vars/Debian.yml)

```
certificate_packages:
  - python-openssl
  - acme-tiny
```

[FreeBSD vars](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-certificate/blob/master/vars/FreeBSD.yml)

```
certificate_packages:
  - security/py-openssl
  - security/py-acme-tiny
```

YMMV.